# Changing picture frame with toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so we have a simple user info editing page.I want to create a toggle button which swaps profile picture border-radius from 0 to 25 and backwards.But the 2nd part doesnt work.I created `if` to check if the boarder radius is 25 already so it will make it 0, but it does not work.Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body onload="buildImage();">
<div class="contents" id="content"></div>
<button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>
<button onclick="changeShape()">ChangeShape</button>
<button onclick="uploadImage()">Upload Image</button>
</body>

<script>
var images = [ 'profile1.png', 'profile2.png','profile3.png'];
var index = 0;
var array_length = 3;
function buildImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = images[index];
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
 }

   function changeImage(){
  var img =     document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
  index++;
  index = index % array_length; 
  img.src = images[index];
}
function changeShape(){
  var shape = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.borderRadius = "25px";
  if(shape.style.borderRadius == 25){
    var shape2 = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.borderRadius = "0px";
  }

}
function uploadImage() {
images.push("profile4.png");
array_length++;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Any ideas why it doesnt work?

Comment: changing 25 to "25px" or to "25" did not work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are uselessly assigning variables in your function by the looks of it.

There is no need to declare shape2. Just declare shape once and then use that to check. Also make sure to check shape.style.borderRadius against a string like "25px" as that will be returned.

**Try something like this:**

```
function changeShape(){
  var shape = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  if(shape.style.borderRadius == "25px"){
    shape.style.borderRadius = "0px";
  }else{
    shape.style.borderRadius = "25px";
  }
}
```

Comment: and an extra question.Can you give me a hint of how to add boarder at the same picture and also make ti change frame whenever the ChangeShape function is called?

Comment: @AggelosSfakianos You want a border that always shows and is the same? If that is the case just add some CSS to it `img{
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
}`

Comment: Yes and no. i want to add a border but i want that border to change shape along with the picture whenever the function is called

Comment: @AggelosSfakianos CSS border works with border radius it will change automatically with out having to do anything in particular. https://jsfiddle.net/p1vkuwjv/